# Send mail via Command-Line and GMail

Tags: email, command-line

I'd like to make a rough framework for a BASH-script which sends me a E-Mail to my GMail account from the same account if a programm exits with non-zero result

```
test "script to execute"
then
//Send me a mail with the content of /worked.txt
else
//Send me a mail with the content of /failed.txt
fi
```

I've read it's like this

```
mail mymail@gmail.com < /worked.txt
```

it does...nothing
No E-Mail, no error, no nothing

-v now says:

```
> foobar@gmail.com... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay... 220
> my-laptop.lan ESMTP Sendmail
> 8.14.3/8.14.3/Debian-9.1ubuntu1; Wed, 10 Nov 2010 18:34:49 +0100; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: localhost(OK)-localhost [127.0.0.1]
> >>> EHLO my-laptop.lan 250-my-laptop.lan Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-EXPN
> 250-VERB 250-8BITMIME 250-SIZE 250-DSN 250-ETRN 250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5
> CRAM-MD5 250-DELIVERBY 250 HELP
> >>> VERB 250 2.0.0 Verbose mode
> >>> MAIL From:<foobar@my-laptop.lan> SIZE=220 AUTH=foobar@my-laptop.lan 250 2.1.0 <foobar@my-laptop.lan>... Sender
> ok
> >>> RCPT To:<foobar@gmail.com>
> >>> DATA 250 2.1.5 <foobar@gmail.com>... Recipient ok 354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
> >>> . 050 <foobar@gmail.com>... Connecting to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. via esmtp... 050 220 mx.google.com ESMTP
> c6si1047453fat.137 050 >>> EHLO my-laptop.lan 050 250-mx.google.com at
> your service, [188.19.112.229] 050 250-SIZE 35651584 050 250-8BITMIME
> 050 250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 050 >>> MAIL From:<foobar@my-laptop.lan>
> SIZE=481 050 250 2.1.0 OK c6si1047453fat.137 050 >>> RCPT
> To:<foobar@gmail.com> 050 250
> 2.1.5 OK c6si1047453fat.137 050 >>> DATA 050 354  Go ahead c6si1047453fat.137 050 >>> . 050 250
> 2.0.0 OK 1289410490 c6si1047453fat.137 050 <foobar@gmail.com>... Sent (OK 1289410490 c6si1047453fat.137) 250 2.0.0 oAAHYn4X005767 Message
> accepted for delivery foobar@gmail.com... Sent (oAAHYn4X005767 Message
> accepted for delivery) Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
> >>> QUIT 221 2.0.0 my-laptop.lan closing connection
```

Comment: This should work fine, try adding the -v option to see what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Alex.  This should work.  Have you checked your SPAM folder on the GMail account?  Perhaps it arrived but was automatically classified as junk mail.

-mark

Comment: No, I just got the following:

050 550-5.7.1 [188.22.234.229] The IP you're using to send mail is not authorized to
050 550-5.7.1 send email directly to our servers. Please use the SMTP relay at your
050 550-5.7.1 service provider instead. Learn more at                         
050 550 5.7.1 http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=10336 p2si2250584bkw.36